# REGEX for dice rolling system and capturing using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to build a javascript dice rolling system that can capture the different sections of a dice roll request in the form of a string from a text box. There are few key parts needed for this and they are in the list bellow:

- Firstly the requested dice must contain the character d or D followed by any length of a whole number eg: D10 or d2 or D1203 and not q1
- Secondly, you can request any number of this roll eg: 10D2 or 20D2 but the number before the D or d is not required.
- Thirdly this number can be modified with by adding minus or times this number by a different number eg: D10+10 or d10*20
- Also, you modify this number by 1 other dice roll like D10+D2
- Also, you can modify the dice roll with a requested number from the user by using brackets with a text string in it eg: D10+(Strength)
- Lastly the last 3 points can be done an infinite number of times if required for some reason eg: 1D10*10+2

I don't even know if this will possible because I am not hugely knowledge in regex. I have made some progress, however, I am hitting a road block with the last bit.
I don't need it to actually do the calculation I just need it to split everything up into groups and validate that the string matches the rules.
This is what I have so far:

```
/([\d]*?)([dD][\d]*)(([\+\-\*])[\d]|([\+\-\*])\(([a-zA-Z]*)\))?/gmi
```

EDIT:
Rewriting what I need as asked for by @sln

I am looking for something that could make a regex that could work with a string like this:

```
10D6([+-*/](number|\(userInput\)|D6))
```

So the user can ask for them to roll 10 D6 dice and add either a predefined number a user input or dice roll. However the 10 is not required neither is everything after D6, however, everything after D6 requires one maths symbol and one of the three things after it. The group after the D6 can be done an infinite number of times. The D6 can be any amount of side as you like as well

Lastly i created a regex101 that has a list of different string that i need it to work with. https://regex101.com/r/VJdgmw/2

Comment: It would be nice to look closer at your regex. However, there is so much ambiguity in your description that there is nothing to relate it to. The key to successful regex is a hard definition of requirements. Rewrite the description as _one entity_ with all the parts. Put all options in brackets: `D5[[+/*10|(user)],[+D5]]` as like you were explaining command line options.

Comment: @sln I have tried doing what you asked at the best of my ability but I dont know if that will help

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the parts as well ?

Comment: I am trying to capture the individual parts after the dice number, the number of dice and the dice side count itself

Comment: How many of these middle combinations do you expect ? `+20+1*2+(Strength)`  Like `+20` and `+1` and `*2` and `+(Strength)` are serialized repeats of the same form `(\d*)(D\d*)(([+*-])\d+|([+*-])\(([A-Z]*)\))*(?:\+(D\d*))?`

Comment: I am trying to capture as many or as few of them as written down really and in any order.

Comment: @sln what you have written down is great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've thinned it out based on my understanding.
[JS demo](https://regex101.com/r/4hVg8q/1)

`/(\d*)(D\d*)((?:[+*-](?:\d+|\([A-Z]*\)))*)(?:\+(D\d*))?/i`

[Formatted](http://www.regexformat.com) / Explained

```
 ( \d* )                       # (1)
 ( D \d* )                     # (2), Dice 1, required
 (                             # (3 start), modifiers
      (?:                           # Cluster
           [+*-]                         # + or - or *
           (?: \d+ | \( [A-Z]* \) )      # either digits, or (name)
      )*                            # End cluster, 0 to many times
 )                             # (3 end)
 (?:
      \+                            # +
      ( D \d* )                     # (4), Dice 2, optional
 )?
```

The middle part `(?:[+*-](?:\d+|\([A-Z]*\)))*` is repeating and so
individually cannot be captured.
However, the entire middle part is captured in group 3 incase you want to process it's contents further.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect and just what i needed.